# Using gson parsing, how will the List type of null object resolved to []

Tags: java, gson

For example:

```
public class Model {
 private String a;
 private List<Integer> b;
 private int c;
} 


@RequestMapping("/test")
public Model test(){
  return new Model;
}
```

In this way,The result is {a:null,b:null,c:0} ,but what I want is {a:"",b:[],c:0}.I know Fastjson can quickly solve this problem, but I have to use Gson.

And now,TypeAdapter helped me solve one of these problems，such as:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new TypeAdapter<String>() {
        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
            if (value == null) {
                out.value("");
                return;
            }
            out.value(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
                in.nextNull();
                return "";
            }
            return in.nextString();
        }
    });
```

But,how will the List type of null object resolved to [] ? Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply provide the default values in the model

```java
public class Model {
    private String a = "";
    private List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
    private int c;
}
```

Or instead of initialising in the variable declaration, you can also put the default values in the getters. For eg.

```java
public String getA() {
    return null == this.a ? "" : this.a;
}
```